# Link doesn't work when placing a div on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the following situation and need help (HTML/CSS/JS related)

I have a div with an image in it (takes the all div space) that when you mouseover it, another div with an image is displayed on top of that (the 2nd div is half transparent). The bottom image has a link. This link doesn't work because of the new half transparent div on top of it.

How can I make the link work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't if you cover it up with another div; regardless of any transparency

Comment: Code please? jsfiddle.net would be helpful?

Comment: You could just have the top image be a child of the link.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/qjVfP/

Comment: @Darren That's not exactly correct. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/6DwNC/

Comment: I can't seem to get a console output on that, though take your word for it :) You learn something new everyday in this job eh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the top image the same link.

Comment: This actually works but I was trying to avoid this solution. The top div contains the image as a background. Thanks!

Comment: The top most element will always be the element clicked on, so you should almost always tie the link to the top most element to keep things simple. You could add some jquery that fires when you click on the top image, but that would be the same result.